# Solving Logarithmic equations- $\log(3x) = 3x - 8$

Tags: logarithms

I had this problem on a worksheet and tried a bunch of different log properties on it, but ended up getting stuck. Any help would be appreciated!
$$\log(3x) = 3x - 8$$

Comment: This will need a numerical method, e.g. linear interpolation or Newton-Raphson, unless you can use non-elementary functions.

Comment: I've never done those before, my teacher gave me this problem in alg2/trig.

Comment: Is the log base $10$ or $e$ or what?

Comment: It's base $10$.